# How much force needs to be applied on a battery cell to maintain contact?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design, springs, battery

I'm designing a battery case for cylindrical li-ion batteries similar to the AA battery cases. We need to avoid spot welding to the cell directly since we want may need to replace some cells later for research purposes.

I'm trying to figure out how much force the spring (battery contact) need to apply to the battery to maintain electrical contact. I'm thinking it could be equal to the weight of the cell, i.e. about 0.5N or 2.8kPa but I couldn't really figure out how other people are doing it.

Would appreciate it if someone could give me some suggestions as to the amount of force it needs. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you think a bit more, it should be obvious that you want rather more than the mass of the cell as the holding force.   The next thing to realize is that batteries are strong, so an overly stiff contact may be annoying to deal with but won't harm the battery.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Yes I agree, should probably consider the acceleration & add in a safety factor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some examples from Lee Spring that could be useful. All the AA size springs listed have 1.75 lb nominal load.

[image: foo]

Source: https://www.leespring.com/battery-springs